# MySQL does not automatically start on boot up after changing bind-address on Debian

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, boot

I installed the mysql-server-5.1 package on Debian 6.  Changed the bind-address to 10.100.1.10 (for internal use), and when I reboot the server it doesn't start up mysql.  This is what the syslog says:

```
Jul 24 18:04:39 server0 mysqld:
Jul 24 18:04:39 server0 mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Jul 24 18:04:46 server0 kernel: [   13.786387] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
Jul 24 18:04:48 server0 /etc/init.d/mysql[1419]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Jul 24 18:04:48 server0 /etc/init.d/mysql[1419]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Jul 24 18:04:48 server0 /etc/init.d/mysql[1419]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Jul 24 18:04:48 server0 /etc/init.d/mysql[1419]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Jul 24 18:04:48 server0 /etc/init.d/mysql[1419]:
```

Comment: After the initial start, if you tried to start up manually mySQL, will it start up then?

Comment: Where's the log entries that describe what actually happened to mysqld?

Comment: @Rilindo Yes, it starts up without a problem.

Comment: @womble They are included in my original post.  Can't you see the log?

Comment: I see an empty entry from mysqld, one from mysqld_safe, and a bunch from the init script.  No *actual* entries from mysqld (and I wouldn't expect them to end up in syslog by default, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

> /usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed

Looks like you didn't include `localhost` in the list when you changed `bind-address`, but you also didn't change `/etc/init.d/mysql` to try connecting to an address that **is** bound. You'll need to do one or the other - the first is probably a better choice.

Comment: So I just have `bind-address 10.100.1.10` and `bind-address 127.0.0.1` to my my.cnf file?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, I have plenty of servers bound to eth devices that are still accessible from lo...